# R: Gsub replacing pattern with skipping a character in replacement

Tags: r, replace, gsub

I want to do a simple replacement using gsub() function in R. See example:

```
#I want: 
Huiswaard 2 Oost
Huiswaard 1 Zuid
Huiswaard 2 West

#To become:
Huiswaard-2-Oost
Huiswaard-1-Oost
Huiswaard-2-Oost
```

By means of the magnificent method of trial & error I tried this:

```
data <- gsub('Huiswaard\\s.\\s>*', "Huiswaard-.-", df)
data <- gsub('Huiswaard\\s.\\s>*', "Huiswaard-.*-", df)
data <- gsub('Huiswaard\\s.\\s>*', "Huiswaard-(.)-", df)
data <- gsub('Huiswaard\\s.\\s>*', "Huiswaard-\\(\\)-", df)
```

All not working. I end up with stuff like:

```
Huiswaard-.-West
```

Does anyone have an idea of how you can use gsub to skip an character in the replacement argument?

Comment: Just do gsub("\\s", "-",data)

Comment: It seems like you just want to replace spaces with ```-```. If so, the comment by @Onyambu will solve your problem. If not, you need to provide more information in your question.

Comment: Thanks @Onyambu, my data example wasn't that clear, there is other data in there as well that is then also affected by that code (e.g. "-D-e-H-o-r-n---N-o-o-r-d-")

Comment: `gsub(x, pattern = "^(Huiswaard)\\s(\\d+)\\s(\\w+)", replacement = "\\1-\\2-\\3")`

Comment: Thanks that solved the problem! @MartinSchmelzer

Comment: What dp you mean with D-e-H...? What is it and what do you want it to be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In regex you can group with parenthesis and back-reference with `\\1`

```
data <- gsub('Huiswaard\\s(\\d)\\s>*', "Huiswaard-\\1-", df)
data
[1] "Huiswaard-2-Oost" "Huiswaard-1-Zuid" "Huiswaard-2-West"
```

If you want to change the suffix, you could also capture the second word with `\\w+` which will capture 1 or more word characters after the space.:

```
data <- gsub('Huiswaard\\s(\\d)\\s\\w+', "Huiswaard-\\1-Oost", df)
data
[1] "Huiswaard-2-Oost" "Huiswaard-1-Oost" "Huiswaard-2-Oost"
```

I use this cheat sheet to help me understand regular expressions: https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/RegExCheatsheet.pdf